# Codenameone: "Warning paint queue size exceeded, please watch the amount of repaint calls"

Tags: java, codenameone

I am getting continuous warning while using below code.

```
TextArea txtLabel = new TextArea(labeltext);
            txtLabel.setUIID("login_title");
            txtLabel.setEditable(false);
            txtLabel.setRows(2);
            txtLabel.setGrowLimit(2);
            txtLabel.setScrollVisible(false);
            txtLabel.setGrowByContent(false);
```

Warnings get rids while using below code.

```
SpanLabel txtLabel = new SpanLabel(labeltext);
            txtLabel.setUIID("login_title");
            txtLabel.setScrollVisible(false);
```

I don't understand why TextArea cause Warning "paint queue size exceeded, please watch the amount of repaint calls"

I have used TextArea because i want multi line label with two rows.

Answer (score 1):

Those warnings happen when there are too many `repaint()` calls in the queue. The major difference between these two calls is the default value for the columns property but I don't think that's the reason for the warning. It's just the thing that finally causes it to tip over the threshold.

You probably have an overly elaborate theme that takes too long to paint (gradients?) and a lot of components within a very elaborate hierarchy that makes it harder to eliminate paint calls. I suggest you review your design within the performance monitor tool and see what can be improved and what is really happening in terms of paint. See this developer guide section:

https://www.codenameone.com/manual/performance-debugging.html